# Unfreeze UI whilst performing a task

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, task

Threading noob here.

I'm trying to make a program that pulls a user's profile data from the osu! website, and while doing so the application freezes. You can't drag around the window or anything. I've tried making a task that returns the result after awaiting but it still freezes

```
private async Task<OsuUserBest[]> GetUserScores()
{

    return await Task.FromResult(osu.GetUserBest(userIdText.Text, 0, 100));
}

private async void OnGoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        userScores = await GetUserScores();
        //...
```

and I've also tried doing `Task.Run( () => {code})` but it tells me that a different thread owns it. and I can't await `osu.GetUserBest(userIdText.Text, 0, 100)` directly because it doesn't contain a definition for `GetAwaiter`.

Again I'm extremely new to threads and asynchronous tasks, so please excuse my idiocy =)

If you want me to provide anything else to help out feel free to ask.

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/iceflarexd/osu-Total-PP-Calculator)

Comment: Assign `userIdText.Text` to a local variable, then use that in `Task.Run(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access UI elements (or any `DispatcherObject` in general) from a thread other than the UI thread (dispatcher thread). Either use the `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` to access those objects or access them (to copy their values) before you run the background operation:

```cs
private async Task<OsuUserBest[]> GetUserScoresAsync()
{
  // Access the DispatcherObject on the UI thread
  string userId = userIdText.Text;

  return await Task.Run(() => osu.GetUserBest(userId, 0, 100));
}
```

Wrapping IO operations like web requests into a `Task.Run` should be an absolute exception. Modern APIs will always expose asynchronous operations.

Comment: thank you so much, worked like a charm, and i even learned something too. that makes a lot of sense; i was trying to figure out this whole time how to "split" the threads without even realizing that grabbing the textbox text was causes it to try to run my method on the main thread, again tysm

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the `GetUserScores` method. You can just use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method directly inside your asynchronous `Click` even handler. This way you'll also avoid violating Microsoft's [recommendation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) about not exposing asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods.

You must be aware that the `Task.Run` method invokes the supplied lambda on a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread, so whatever code you are offloading should have no affinity with the UI thread. Which in practice means that you should not touch (or even sniff) any UI element from the offloaded code. Interacting with UI components should be done exclusively on the UI thread.

```
private async void OnGoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string userId = userIdText.Text;
        OsuUserBest[] userScores = await Task.Run(() => osu.GetUserBest(userId, 0, 100));
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```